# error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am getting this error when compiling

```
queue.c: In function ‘enqueue’:
queue.c:25:10: error: ‘node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
queue.c:25:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Why is this appearing? I don't understand how to define the variable node.

Here's my code for enqueue:

```
   void enqueue(Queue* queue, int value){
      QNode* node =(QNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct QNode));
      node->data = value;
      if(queue->size == 0){
        q->front = node;
        q->rear = node;
      }else{
        queue->rear->next = node;
        queue->rear = node;
        queue->size++;
      }
}
```

At the beginning of the file, I define QNode and Queue in this way:

```
typedef struct QNode;
struct QNode{
  struct QNode* next;
  int data;
} QNode;

typedef struct Queue{
  int size;
  struct QNode* front;
  struct QNode* rear;
} Queue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although technically not an error:

```
typedef struct QNode;
struct QNode{
  ...
```

Its better to write as:

```
typedef struct QNode {
    ...
```

You also have:

```
if(queue->size == 0){
        q->front = node;
        q->rear = node;
```

Where is q defined?

Maybe you meant:

```
if(queue->size == 0){
        queue->front = node;
        queue->rear = node;
```

Comment: I think `typedef struct QNode;` is actually legal, though it's useless. It makes the following `struct QNode...` declaration declare a single object called `QNode`, rather than making `QNode` a typedef.

Comment: Yes!  A corollary result is that no declaration exists for 'node' in the void enqueue() function (further down).  The compiler will then complain about the use of an undeclared identifier, namely 'node.'